# How can I call a constructor in main() c++?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, makefile, program-entry-point

I have two classes.

fileInfo.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class fileInfo{

private:

string fileName;
string fileType;

public:
/** 
**/
fileInfo(string s){
    fileName = s;
    fileType = "hellooo";

}
string getName() {
    return fileName;
}
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

fileInfo f("test");
std::cout << f.getName();

}
```

The fileInfo object "f" is not being initialized and I get an error saying that fileInfo is not in scope. I am using a makefile to compile my code which looks like.

```
all: main.cpp fileInfo.cpp
    g++ main.cpp fileInfo.cpp -o out
```

Comment: You need to put your class declaration in a header file and include it. Don't confuse classes with files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the correct way to do it:

fileInfo.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class fileInfo{

private:

  string fileName;
  string fileType;

public:

  fileInfo(string s);

  string getName();
};
```

fileInfo.cpp:

```
#include "fileInfo.h"

fileInfo::fileInfo(string s){
    fileName = s;
    fileType = "hellooo";
}

string fileInfo::getName() {
    return fileName;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "fileInfo.h"

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  fileInfo f("test");
  std::cout << f.getName();

}
```

Comment: Do I have to do anything with my makefile? I am still getting the fileInfio out of scope error.

Comment: Nope your Makefile is fine. This compiles and runs correctly for me. I get the output "test".  Make sure you have copied the files correctly...